# Static polymorphism with dependent internal class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism

I have the following - simplified -- C++11 code used to abstract away reading from an object store or from the file system:

- `ObjectLikeReader::open` is a virtual function returning a `Handle` implementation.
- `Handle::read` reads something from the underlying object.

```cpp
class Handle {
   public:
    virtual std::string read() = 0;
    virtual ~Handle() = default;
};

class ObjectLikeReader {
   public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Handle> open() = 0;
    virtual ~ObjectLikeReader() = default;
};

// Specialization

class FileReader : public ObjectLikeReader {
   public:
    std::unique_ptr<Handle> open() override;

   private:
    class InternalHandle;
};

class FileReader::InternalHandle : public Handle {
   public:
    InternalHandle(){};
    std::string read() override {
        return "hello";
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Handle> FileReader::open() {
    return std::unique_ptr<Handle>(new InternalHandle());
}

std::string read(ObjectLikeReader* reader) {
    return reader->open()->read();
}

int main() {
    FileReader r;
    std::cout << read(&r) << std::endl;
}
```

All the dispatch is done using virtual functions, and working perfectly fine. Apart from performance in tight loop, which commands having a look at static polymorphism:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class Handle {
   public:
    std::string read() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->read();
    }

   protected:
    ~Handle() = default;
};

template <class T, class H>
class ObjectLikeReader {
   public:
    Handle<H> open() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->open();
    }

   protected:
    ~ObjectLikeReader() = default;
};

// Specialization

class FileReaderHandle : Handle<FileReaderHandle> {
   public:
    FileReaderHandle(){};
    std::string read() {
        return "hello";
    }
};

class FileReader : public ObjectLikeReader<FileReader, FileReaderHandle> {
   public:
    FileReaderHandle open() {
        return FileReaderHandle();
    }
};

int main() {
    FileReader r;
    std::cout << r.open().read() << std::endl;
}
```

I am not quite satisfied of this implementation. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality as the second example?:

- Without requiring the double template parameter (traits maybe? not sure...),
- Ideally without having to make the handle class public.

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** Fixed stupid missing constructor definition causing compilation error.

Comment: There is no substitute for virtual inheritance. It exists for a reason. The template-based approach has one obvious design flaw: each instance of a template is a unique class, and you can no longer define operations on any handle. Using a template defeats the original purpose of abstracting away file operations.

Comment: Your second example doesn't rely on `ObjectLikeReader ` and `Handle` at all. You can drop the parts where you derive from `ObjectLikeReader<FileReader, FileReaderHandle>` and `Handle<FileReaderHandle>`, or remove `open` and `read` functions from those classes, and the calling code would still work without changes ([Demo 1](https://rextester.com/XLYJL37539), [Demo 2](https://rextester.com/WODHI34402)). You are fooling yourself - there's no polymorphism there, static or otherwise.

Comment: `ObjectLikeReader::open` performs [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) - it returns an instance of `Handle<H>`, not `H` (a class derived from `Handle<H>`). If someone then calls `read()` on that instance, the program would exhibit undefined behavior (`static_cast<T*>(this)` would cast to a class that the object pointed to by `this` is not actually derived from). So it's a good thing your example never actually calls `ObjectLikeReader::open`